# Произведение квадратов первых двухсот чисел

Tags: java

Необходимо составить программу нахождения произведения квадратов первых двухсот чисел.
Вот что я пробовал:

```
long s = 1;
    int j;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 200; i++) {
        j = (int) Math.pow(i,2);
        s *= j;
    }
    System.out.println(s);
```

Выводит 0, так как по-видимому выхожу за рамки long. Каким образом ещё можно решить эту задачу?

Comment: использовать double

Comment: по-видимому выхожу за рамки long.  - совсем чуток я думаю

Comment: BigInteger используйте. И не стоит для нахождения квадрата применять pow, достаточно умножить число на себя.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В java и в других языках существуют большие числа. [BigInteger и BigDecimal](https://metanit.com/java/tutorial/12.2.php).

```
    BigInteger a = BigInteger.valueOf(2147483647);
    BigInteger b = BigInteger.valueOf(2147483641);
    //a *= b;  
    // так нельзя, так как это объекты, а не примитивы
    a = a.multiply(b); 
    // так можно - помните, что применение этой ф-ции не изменяет этот объект - 
    // оно возвращает новый
```

Нужно переписать так:

```
BigInteger s = BigInteger.valueOf(1);
for(int i = 2; i <= 200; i++) {
    s = s.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf((long) i * i));
}
System.out.println(s);
```

Соответственно, вывод будет следующим:

> 621981231756379489999997501700030226361030042908402135795585416076780567701229627071194748755274771867550481130867332728398608915678217606208944334143532903157416015053231992085653846275159616127812272870349795208758168675609821292383968189620347359298821336964567268936282003057371855944848505049857604569455105033587666178052186125598590101814860460233644389300432456960009702905584857393518877079243717213370983146491503406155228997954249347719005783769360467152555665800216223615428450836858053400856713359967484823371026535062161096211713506798207812398746913836648755132232834523663952442186966337759051603462287553956523494664588575257708095078400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Comment: Совсем чуток не влезает в long :)))

Comment: @Miron уберите pow он не нужен 200*200 умножается легко

Comment: Лишь 2 в 2491 степени больше этого числа(начинается с 7, а не с 6).